# Access a local machine form outside the LAN

Tags: ftp, remote-desktop, lan, portforwarding

Is there a way to access a machine from outside the LAN without port forwarding?

I have two scenarios in my current setup port forwarding is complicating:

1. I have two FTP servers on the same router I want to access from outside
2. I want to Remote Control/Access files on Windows computers on the network

Right now, the first option is possible, but it needs reconfiguring the router, while other one seems impossible outside the LAN.

Is there something like [global IP address]/[machine name] or [global IP address]/[Local IP address]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need more information. Are these addresses IPv4 [RFC 1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) addresses, *publicly* routed addresses, or [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)?

If they are in the RFC1918 (10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x) address space then, simply no. Those addresses are not publicly routed and therefore must be translated to a non-RFC 1918 address.

Otherwise, yes, you can.

Comment: Yes, local addresses are in IPv4 address space (e.g. my is 192.168.1.5). Is there a way to translate them into other addresses?

Comment: with your requirements no.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers should be available to the public - the answer will be "no".

If you plan to give a limited number of users (for example, only you) access to this servers then you have some options:

- **Use SSH tunnels** with, for example, [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and set up a Forwarding for each service you want to expose to your computer and access it over localhost:port.

  - localhost:21001 --> 192.168.1.3:21 (FTP1)
  - localhost:21002 --> 192.168.1.4:21 (FTP2)
  - Advantage: you can setup your "port-forwardings" at clinet-side
  - Disadvantage: you need a *router* or another computer running the SSH *server*
- **Use a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)** (for example, [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN), [PPTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol), etc.) to get access to your LAN from outside. Then you can act like you are in your LAN.

  - Advantages:

    - easy to use if setup properly
    - you can use almost every protocol
  - Disadvantage: Need to setup VPN Service/Gateway